# The sum of a Quadratic sum

Tags: java

Its been 3 years since I have done java so I'm pretty rusty.

> **Problem:** Quadratic equation is a(x^2) + b(x) + c (a, b, c are the coefficients)
>
> ```
> public static Quadratic sum(Quadratic q1, Quadratic q2)
> ```
>
> **Postcondition:** The return value is the quadratic expression obtained by adding q1 and q2. For example, the C coefficient of the return value is the sum of q1's c coefficient and q2's coefficient.

I am stuck trying to remember how to add these quadratics and then returning their sum. Here's what I have. I'm pretty sure I'm off by a bit and have made many changes, but I'm looking for a little guidance.

```
public static Quadratic sum(Quadratic q1, Quadratic q2){
    int newA =(q1.a + q2.a);
    int newB =(q1.b + q2.b);
    int newC =(q1.c + q2.c);   
    return; 
}
```

Comment: `return new Quadratic(newA, newB, newC)` maybe?

Comment: How to add these quadratics is a math question, not a Java or even a programming question. How to return their sum is just a matter of `return`, so the real question is how do you create a `Quadratic` with the new values? @Luiggi's guess looks plausible, but we haven't seen the `Quadratic` ctor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return a new `Quadratic` object with the sums of individual coefficients.
There is more than one way to do this. Here is one:

```
public static Quadratic sum(Quadratic q1, Quadratic q2) {
    int newA =(q1.a + q2.a);
    int newB =(q1.b + q2.b);
    int newC =(q1.c + q2.c);   
    return new Quadratic(newA, newB, newC); 
}
```

For this to work, you need to have the following constructor in your `Quadratic` class:

```
Quadratic(int a, int b, int c) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
}
```

So your class would look something like:

```
class Quadratic {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    Quadratic(int a, int b, int c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }        
}
```

If you don't want to add a new constructor, you can assign the values individually before returning a new `Quadratic`. This would be another way of achieving the same thing:

```
public static Quadratic sum(Quadratic q1, Quadratic q2){
    Quadratic result = new Quadratic(); 
    result.a =(q1.a + q2.a);
    result.b =(q1.b + q2.b);
    result.c =(q1.c + q2.c);   
    return result;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment, if you want to use your `setQuadratic()` method, you need to put it inside the `Quadratic` class. Like this:

```
class Quadratic {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    void setQuadratic(int newA, int newB, int newC) {
        a = newA;
        b = newB;
        c = newC;
    }        
}

// ... rest of your code

public static Quadratic sum(Quadratic q1, Quadratic q2){
    Quadratic result = new Quadratic();
    int newA =(q1.a + q2.a);
    int newB =(q1.b + q2.b);
    int newC =(q1.c + q2.c);   
    result.setQuadratic(newA, newB, newC);
    return result; 
}
```

However, having a constructor do instantiation and initialization in a single step (i.e. `new Quadratic(newA, newB, newC)`) is simpler/cleaner code than having two methods: a constructor to instantiate and a set() method to initialize, which is what you currently have.

I would suggest going with the first solution presented above.

Comment: public Quadratic(){
  int a=0;
  int b=0;
  int c=0;
  int x=0;
 }
 

 public void setQuadratic(int newA, int newB, int newC){
  a=newA;
  b=newB;
  c=newC;
 }


Then in the demo class I give (a,b,c) a value. (I cant get it to show in code form for some reason)

Comment: thank you so much! that helped a lot. I have one more question about how that would adjust the last part I need to do which is:

public static Quadratic scale(double r, Quadratic q)

//the return value is the quadratic expression obtained by multiplying each of q's coefficients by the number r.

for that I can do something along the lines of 

result.a=result.a*r;

 correct? but with r being a double is there a easy way for me to change the int's in result over to doubles?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Quadratic sum(Quadratic q1, Quadratic q2){
    return new Quadratic( q1.a+q2.a , q1.b+q2.b , q1.c+q2.c ); 
}
```